# Ansible: Need Information regarding the connection with Database(Oracle/MySql)

Tags: ansible

> My Requirement is that i am able to fetch the host name and java version from host, take those values to local host and store it in the database. 
>   I am able to fetch the java version on local host, the last step is to store these variable values in Database.. Can anyone suggest how can i proceed with that

```
---
- hosts: myserver
  tasks:

  - name: Get the Host Name
    shell: host $(hostname -i) | awk '{print $NF }'|sed 's/\.$//'
    register: hosts
  - set_fact: the_hosts=hosts.stdout
  - debug: var={{the_hosts}}

  - name: Fetch Java Version
    shell: /opt/app/java/jdk/jdk180_66/ 
64bit/bin/java -version 2>&1 | grep version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/"//g'
    register: result
  - set_fact: the_count=result.stdout
  - debug: var={{the_count}}

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - debug: var=hostvars['zlp12036']['result']['stdout']
  - debug: var=hostvars['zlp12037']['result']['stdout']
  - debug: var=hostvars['zlp12036']['hosts']['stdout']
  - debug: var=hostvars['zlp12037']['hosts']['stdout']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what's the point of determining java version, if you have `jdk180_66` hardcoded? Also, consider using `ansible_hostname` variable to determine hostname of machine.

If you have a database client installed on your localhost, from where you want to run query, you can use shell module, in case of mysql this may look like

`- name: insert ansible result
   shell: mysql -u {{ db.user }} -p {{ db.password }} -e "use {{ db.name }}; INSERT INTO {{ db.table }} values( '{{ hostvars[item].hosts.stdout}}','{{ hostvars[item].result.stdout}}');"
   with_items: groups['myserver']`

Where `db.user` `db.password` and `db.name` variables are storing your connection to the database (but it's better to store password inside `~/.my.cnf` on server), `db.table` is a name of your table and `myserver` is the name of inventory group where your servers are stored. Adjust this command for your own schema, since you haven't specified layout of your table.

For oracle you should use equivalent `sqlplus` command.